# How to count occurrences of each unique value within a column of lists Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a DataFrame looks like this:

[image: A column that contains lists of string]

I want to count the occurrence of each value in those lists.

The output I want is a DataFrame looks like:

| Genre | Occurrence |
| --- | --- |
| Drama | 12224 |
| Crime | 5699 |
| Comedy | 1314 |
| ... | ... |

I've tried `value_counts()` and the result is the frequency of lists but the elements within them.

```
[Comedy, Drama]                                28
[Comedy, Drama, Romance]                       27
[Comedy]                                       25
[Action, Crime, Thriller]                      22
[Crime, Drama, Thriller]                       21
                                               ..
[Crime, Drama, Horror, Music, Thriller]         1
[Adventure, Drama, Romance]                     1
[Drama, Romance, War]                           1
[Action, Adventure, Fantasy]                    1
[Action, Comedy, Horror, Mystery, Thriller]     1
```

I also tried to combine the column to a list of lists then count but nested `for` loops is not a good way. I'd love better solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can `explode` and then count the values

```py
df["genre"].explode().value_counts()
```

`explode` will spread out the contents of those lists into each row on their own, so that value_counts will count them as separate entities.

Comment: I hadn't seen .explode() before, thanks, it's really useful